# MSAL SDK on Android TV crash SSL Exception

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-ad-msal, android-tv

I’m developing an app for android tv (Xamarin Android), and I’m using MSAL SDK in order to login and use API MS Graph. The same steps on android phone works correctly, I call to login, and app opens chrome or other web browser in order to login. But on Android TV, it crashes with an exception of  javax.net.ssl.sslhandshakeexception  On Android TV, it is launched as webview on app due to Android TV doesn’t have a browser.
Could you tell me what I should do in order to avoid the exception of SSL of SDK?

Edit:
I have been testing with other device on simulator and Android TV with Android 9 works perfectly. If I test it with Android TV with Android 10, it crashes with SSL Exception. Are there something that I can do in order to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem on physical device and simulator has been resolved with reset of factory on physical device and simulators.